# How to get content from Div which have other HTML tags using Regexp

Tags: php, html, regex

I have div which contain other `html tags` along with `text`

I want to extract only text from this div OR inside all `html tags`

```
<div class="rpr-help m-chm">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2 class="h6">Repair Help</h2>
                </div><!-- /end .header -->
                <div class="inner m-bsc">
                    <ul>


                        <li><a href="#videol">Repair Video</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#qa1">Repair Q&amp;A</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                    <div>
                    <br>
                    <span class="h4">Cross Reference Information</span><br>
                    <p>Part Number 285753A (AP3963893) replaces  1195967, 280152, 285140, 285743, 285753, 3352470, 3363664, 3364002, 3364003, 62672, 62693, 661560, 80008, 8559748, AH1485646, EA1485646, PS1485646.
                    <br>
                    </p>
                    </div>

            </div>
```

Here is my `Regexp`

```
preg_match_all("/<div class=\"rpr-help m-chm\">(.*)<\/.*>/s", $urlcontent, $description);
```

Its working fine whenever I assign this complete `div` to `$urlcontent` variable.

But when I am fetching data from real url like `$urlcontent = "www.test.com/test.html";` 
its returning complete webpage script.

How can I get inside content of `<div class="rpr-help m-chm">` ?

Is there any correction require in my regexp?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to parse HTML/XHTML by regex. [Source](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

> You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by
>   regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML

Based on the language you use, Please consider using a thirdpart library for HTML parsing.

Comment: Okay, Thanks, Thats was good article. So is there any other way to parse the data.

Comment: @RahulDambare assuming you use php, this seems to be an active and good library to adapt https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser

Comment: The seminal SO post is: [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
use this function

    function GetclassContent($tagStart,$tagEnd,$content)
    {
        $first_step = explode( $tagStart,$content );
        $second_step = explode($tagEnd,$first_step[1] );
        return $second_step[0];
    }

Steps to Use Above function 
$website="www.test.com/test.html";
$content=file_get_contents($website);
$tagStart ='<div  class="rpr-help m-chm">';
$tagEnd   = "</div >";
$RequiredContent = GetclassContent($tagStart,$tagEnd,$content);
```

Comment: it contains other </div> also. what if it take first end tag, then it will skip other contain

Comment: @RahulDambare Now you can customize the 'GetclassContent' function to get the required or desired result.